# Show that this initial value problem doesn't have a unique solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the function given by $y(t)={t}^2$ satisfies the initial value problem $\frac{dy}{dt} =2\sqrt{y}$, t$\ge$0; $y(0)=0$ 
Show that this initial value problem does not have a unique solution, by giving another function which solves the same problem.

I get the first part but how do I show that there isn't a unique solution?

Answer (score 2):

Hint. As regards the second question, take $y(t)=0$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $y(t)=(t-1)^2$ for $t\geq 1$. Does this function satisfy the given Cauchy problem?
Now can you find two more solutions (one is trivial ;-))?